# C++ sort an array in descending order using a separate function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Hi there need help with an assignment in C++
I must randomly generate 100 numbers under 250 in an array and then sort them in descending order using a separate function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sample[100];
    int t;

    for (t=0; t<250; ++t) {
        sample[t] = (double) (rand()%100);
    }


    for (t=0; t<100; ++t) {
        cout<< sample[t]<< "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to successfully complete part 1, would appreciate some help in the sorting of the random numbers.

Comment: these parts may be helpful: `#include <algorithm>` and `std::begin` and `std::end` and `std::sort` and `std::greater`

Comment: Your code doesn't match the description: you produce 250 numbers under 100 instead of 100 numbers under 250. You also produce an array overflow. Whether `rand()` produces random numbers is a separate question but, I guess, they are random enough for your needs.

Comment: So, you just having problems sorting? or is it the reverse-order part you are finding hard?

Comment: Dietmar Kuhl, it seems to work fine, im getting my 100 random numbers under 250 perfectly. Yes Richard its just the sorting Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

It even has one of its examples directly relevant to your problem.

Comment: So, I assume you followed the link?

Comment: Yes however i still cant grasp how to apply it to my own code

Comment: ok, try std::sort (sample, sample+100, std::greater<double>())

check out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/ to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting algorithms are one of the cornerstones of most beginner computer science courses and are a rather important study in the science itself. They are also very well [documented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) on the internet.

You can ask for help with specific errors but asking for us to write it for you is not going to teach you anything.